# jQuery - replace standard radio button click() action

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm using radio buttons with some Ajax loaded content. Basicly due to other functionality of web, radio buttons are completly jQuery based. So whenever i click them certain action is called. Anyway - I can't come up to solution with 1 problem. I want radio buttons to be disabled whenever ajax content is not loaded. I've added flag before/on callback of ajax content, so now click() action i've defined on radio buttons doesn't work whenever ajax content is being loaded.

Altough standard radio buttons action still seem to work (using "return false;"). By standard i mean - radio button is being checked after clicked - while nothing should happen. Any ideas how to disable it? Below is part of the code:

```
$('#radiobutton1').click(function() {
    if (!$('#rightImage').parent().children().is(':animated') && loadrelease==true) {
      actions to do here
    }
    return false;
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the start of your ajax call, disable the radio button:

```
$('#radiobutton1').attr('disabled','disabled')
```

On completion, turn it back on again:

```
$('#radiobutton1').attr('disabled','')
```

Comment: $('#radiobutton1').attr('disabled','') didnt work for me, so replaced it with .removeAttr('disabled') and it's fine

Answer (score 2):

I believe you wish to disable all radio buttons when an ajax call is submitted. You can do this with the ajax events. I suggest add a class to all radio buttons that you want to disable during an ajax call.

```
   $.ajax({
         url: '../Controller/Action',
         data: { data: 'data'},
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'post',
         beforeSend: function () {
             //Disable your radio buttons here
              $('.ajaxRadioButtons').attr('disabled','true');
           },
         success: function (data) {

         },
        error: function () {

        },
        complete: function () {
        //enable your radio buttons here
        $('.ajaxRadioButtons').attr('disabled','');
 }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you - obviously both answers are great

Comment: Would love to but need more reputation - will do that as soon as I'll get some ;)

Comment: I see that. Welcome to StackOverFlow.com